# How can i extend a class in a library like Armadillo?

Tags: c++, extend, armadillo

I'm working with 3D vectors for 3d Graphics.
I created a class vec3 to add functions like  getX, getY, getZ, setX, setY, setZ, setXYZ... and so on.

```
#include <armadillo>
using namespace arma;

// An extension to VEC class for Armadillo for 3D graphics.
class vec3 : public vec
{
public:

    // Constructor inits vector to 0,0,0
    vec3() : vec(3,fill::zeros) {}
    ~vec3(void){};

    double getX() const { return at(0); }
    double getY() const { return at(1); }
    double getZ() const { return at(2); }

    void   setX(double x){ ?????? = x; }
};
```

I found myself lost in a very unusual situation i never found:

***How do i use (i) access to elements... inside the class?***

For the getter function, as you can see, it is easy since we have an "at" function, at least.
But how do i create a setX function, that inserts in the 0 position of the vector the given element...

I tried this(i) , obviously didn't work. I feel so newbie here...
Where is "vec" built over?. A std::vector?... Am i doing right by doing this simple stuff?

Comment: I don't know enough about the base class (vec) to answer your question.  Is the code for the base class public?  Can you post at least the public header?

Comment: Yeah, i thought about that.I guess , then, i should use the base class...right?. If it were a std::vector... what should i do,then? Let me check.

Comment: Which library is armadillo? Is it [this](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col) one?

Comment: @StevenHansen It is open source. I opened the include file that redirects to all files (i dont find VEC.. sadly) but i saw it includes: #include <vector>  On top. I guess it is related to std: Then, how would i do it inside if VEC is itself a template vector?

Comment: Well, *if* the base class is stl::vector, and *if* x is the first element, then it would be `this[0]=x`.  Without seeing the source code, it may be easier to use composition instead of inheritance.  ("Has a" instead of "Is a").

Comment: I found out VEC derives from MAT, and mat is defined in a file called mat_bones.hpp that has this operator () and [].
 arma_inline arma_warn_unused const eT& operator() (const uword i) const;   ... But i cannot see the implementation.

Comment: Personally I would just change your class to use composition instead.  It would only introduce a minor additional amount of hassle during coding, but would have full access to all the functionality of Armadillo's vec public interface.

Comment: @StevenHansen Ok. Sounds ok, too. I have to return vec type later on. I could do a casting, in the current case, or make a function to return the included vec inside...

Comment: @Gasim Yes. It is THAT library. It is quite famous i guess.

Comment: The implementation of the [Mat](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat) class is in _Mat_meat.hpp_. The _vec_ class is actually a typedef for the [Col](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col) class using _double_ as the elements (ie. _vec_ = _Col<double>_). Note that Armadillo already defines a [vec3](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_col) class (typedef for _Col<double>::fixed<3>_), so you may want to name your class something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at(0) = x;` should work if vec is derived from std::vector because at function can return non-constant reference.

Comment: Yeah! This worked. I wonder what should i do if i had not that function, for example. 

Is it better to extend, than to include an element of the class? I guess that takes more memory.

Comment: Include (or composition) is a perfectly good option, especially if you don't introduce other *data*.

Comment: Another thought - generally it isn't wise to rely on a particular implementation provided by a third party.  They may decide that they want to change the internals completely in their next version.

Comment: So... using at() should be wrong too, right?
I rely on their implementation because i have to use it. This easy vectors could be done outside, but i was told to do so. What should i do, then?. I have to return , later on, vec types. But casting vec3 to vec should work fine, right?

Comment: Well, at() is part of the defined interface.  You are supposed to be able to count on that.  What *may not be* defined is which base classes the library uses (or any internal implementation for that matter).  So, while VEC may be a child of MAT for now, which may in turn be a child of std::vector, who knows if that will be the case in future versions *unless* it has been specified as part of the API.

Comment: I doubt that the implementation of Armadillo's [vec](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col) class will change its parent. It's explicitly documented as being derived from the [mat](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat) class.  The _mat_ class represents a matrix, while the _vec_ class is a restricted matrix. This makes sense mathematically, as a vector is defined as a matrix with either one row or column.